# Problems finding Borel σ-algebra

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, borel-sets

I always have problems finding the Borel σ-algebra. For example I have taken this exercise. I really don't know how to start and how to proceed. Can someone help me?

Let $X = \left \{ A \subseteq  \mathbb{R} :  \text{number of }A < \infty \right \}$. Find $σ(B)$.

Is there a general way/procedure to find it?